# MVC - Using Custom Class for Model Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to preface this by saying, I am a web developer that started in C++ before learning ASP.NET C#.

So I have a Model in my web app that has a property that I would like use a custom class as the datatype of the property. I am not sure where to store the custom class in the folder structure in Visual Studio. Also, I am not sure I am setting this up correctly.

**Custom Class**

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
}

public ClassName(int v1)
{
    value1 = v1;
    value2 = v2
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassName> ClassNames {get; set;}
}
```

I do not want the custom class on the database. I have been doing Code First with Migrations in Visual Studio and keeps trying to push the custom class into the database. Any ideas on what I could have setup wrong or what I need to do to get what I am looking for.

Comment: Is your `Model` class also hooked up through your Entity Framework `DbContext` to be retrieved from the database? You should separate your Models from your DTO objects for this type of scenario. You'll need to show more about the EF side of your code.

Comment: What is your intended outcome?  Are you trying to store Model objects to the database without sending the ClassNames collection at all?  If so, you could just add the [NotMapped] attribute.  If you're trying to store the collection in a different format than the Code First generated table, however, you'll have more work to do.

Comment: If you dont want the custom class in the database then do an add-migration IgnoreChanges... This will create the migration class and then in the UP and DOWN functions just delete any code you dont want

Answer (score 0):

As far as folder structure -
Look into the Model View Controller pattern for Asp.Net, very nice pattern. Store your models in a folder called 'models', controllers under 'controllers' Views under 'views' etc.

as far as using 'classname' in your table, im not too sure if you can use classes for rows. not sure how the database table would accomdate that.

Perhaps you need to create another table for classname, and then reference those records back to your first table using a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `public class Model` in the database then do an `add-migration IgnoreChanges` using the VS Package Manager Console.

This will create the migration class called `IgnoreChanges` and then in the `public override void Up()` and `public override void Down()` functions just delete any code you dont want.

like this:

```
public partial class IgnoreChanges : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
       // No code here
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
       // No code here
    }
}
```

Perform an `update-database` and volia... no changes are added to the database.

You are basically fooling Migrations into thinking it has run your model into the database.

Migrations takes a snapshot of your database at the time you perform an `add-migration` so by removing the code you don't want published to the database, migrations will still recognise that your change has been generated, even though you removed the code from the `public override void Up()` and `public override void Down()` functions

Hope this makes sense